# Adding Argmax Constraint in JuMP?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm attempting to add in a constraint to a JuMP 0.2.0 (Gurobi as a solver) model that reads in the [original paper](https://www.mit.edu/~dbertsim/papers/Machine%20Learning%20under%20a%20Modern%20Optimization%20Lens/Optimal_classification_trees_MachineLearning.pdf) (pg 12) as follows:

c_t = argmax(N_kt) for k in 1...K

This constraint is designed to read through a matrix column by column, locate the *index* of the cell with the greatest value in that column, and assign that index to a cell c_t.

While Julia has an `argmax` function in the Base package, this function does not work in JuMP.  Attempting to execute

```
for t in 1:T
    @constraint(model, c_t == argmax(N_Kt[:,t])
end
```

throws an error of `DenseAxisArray does not support this operation.`  Changing `N_Kt` to a non-dense JuMP array gets rid of that error, but instead throws an error of `MethodError: no method matching isless(::VariableRef, ::VariableRef)`.

Is there an equivalent function for `argmax` within JuMP that I've managed to miss, or alternately, is there a clever way to reformulate this constraint?  I've toyed with list comprehensions, i.e.

```
for t in t_l 
    for i in 1:num_features
        @constraint(model, [i for k in 1:6 if N_kt[i,t] >= N_kt[k,t]] == c_t[t])
    end
end
```

but Julia throws various errors when attempting this kind of formulation.  This final approach of "set c_t equal to the index whose corresponding value is greater than or equal to all other values in this range" seems promising, but again, even the snippet above generates an error.  Is there a better way to add in a conditional statement to a constraint declaration that I'm missing?

Thanks for any help you can offer here!

Comment: Go to page 13 of the reference you give which gives you instructions how to linearize the problem.